# Восстановление неизвестных значений матрицы

Tags: python, математика, numpy, scikit-learn, scipy

Как восстановить недостающие значения матрицы в Python, зная, что векторы линейно зависимы?
например, в этом примере 2-й вектор больше, чем первый в 2 раза, а 3-й больше 2-го в 10 (но на деле мы не знаем эту зависимость).

```
import numpy as np

nan = np.NaN
data = np.array([[1,  nan,  5,   6,   nan, 20],
                 [2,  nan, nan,  nan,  4,  nan],
                 [20, nan, 100,  120,  40, nan]])
```

**Ожидаемый результат:** 2-й столбец может быть заменен, возможно, на основе распределения для каждого вектора (интуитивно представляю результат как то так)

```
[[  1.  7   5.   6.    2.   20.]
 [  2.  14  10.  12.   4.   40.]
 [ 20.  140 100. 120.  40.  400.]]
```

Матрица может быть больше, и линейное соотношение между векторами может быть выражено не так явно, как в этом примере, поэтому требуется универсальное решение.

**Для этого требуется:**

1. найти коэффициенты зависимости
2. заполнить пробелы
3. интерполировать оставшиеся пропуски

подскажите как это сделать?

Comment: К сожалению, я не понял как вы заполнили 2-й столбец

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно поробовать так:

Сначала создаем Pandas DataFrame для удобства:

```
import pandas as pd  #  pip install pandas

In [24]: df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

получился следующий DF:

```
In [25]: df
Out[25]:
      0   1      2      3     4     5
0   1.0 NaN    5.0    6.0   NaN  20.0
1   2.0 NaN    NaN    NaN   4.0   NaN
2  20.0 NaN  100.0  120.0  40.0   NaN
```

теперь применим известные правила линейных зависимостей:

```
In [30]: df.loc[1].fillna(df.loc[0]*2, inplace=True)

In [31]: df.loc[2].fillna(df.loc[1]*10, inplace=True)

In [32]: df.loc[0].fillna(df.loc[1]/2, inplace=True)
```

получим:

```
In [33]: df
Out[33]:
      0   1      2      3     4      5
0   1.0 NaN    5.0    6.0   2.0   20.0
1   2.0 NaN   10.0   12.0   4.0   40.0
2  20.0 NaN  100.0  120.0  40.0  400.0
```

наконец интерполируем DataFrame по строкам, чтобы избавиться от оставшихся неизвестных:

```
In [36]: df.interpolate(axis=1, inplace=True)

In [37]: df
Out[37]:
      0     1      2      3     4      5
0   1.0   3.0    5.0    6.0   2.0   20.0
1   2.0   6.0   10.0   12.0   4.0   40.0
2  20.0  60.0  100.0  120.0  40.0  400.0
```

Comment: А если данных очень много? и эта зависимость не такая строгая как в примере? и если мы просто знаем что строки зависят друг от друга но не знаем в какой пропорции?
есть же какие то меоды вроде таких  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32228374/fill-predict-unknown-values-of-matrix-in-python

это хорошо что я пример такой привел) но имелось ввиду, что мы просто знаем что зависмость есть, а какая она - не знаем

Comment: У вас вопрос в том как интерполировать 2D матрицу или в том как найти коэфициенты зависимостей?

Comment: Как интерполировать линейно-зависимую матрицу у которой мы не знаем истинную зависимость их векторов-строк

Comment: @Ste_kd, IMO, есть смысл разбить задачу на несколько: 1) найти коэффициенты зависимостей если вы знаете что зависимости присутствуют. 2) воспользоваться полученной информацией чтобы точнее заполнить пропуски. 3) воспользоваться интерполяцией для заполнения оставшихся пропусков

Comment: указал в вопросе, но всеравно не вкурсе как это сделать, если не вы, как всегда, то никто не поможет)

Comment: @Ste_kd, не помню как можно эффективно найти коэффициенты... :(

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

nan = np.nan
p1 = 2
p2 = 10

data = np.array([[1,  nan,  5,   6,   nan, 10],
                 [2,  nan, nan,  nan,  4,  nan],
                 [20, nan, 100,  120,  40, nan]])

for idx, i in enumerate(data[0]):
  if not np.isnan(i):
    data[1][idx] = i * p1
    data[2][idx] = i * p1 * p2;

for idx, i in enumerate(data[1]):
  if not np.isnan(i):
    data[0][idx] = i / p1
    data[2][idx] = i * p2;

for idx, i in enumerate(data[2]):
  if not np.isnan(i):
    data[1][idx] = i / p2
    data[0][idx] = i / p1 / p2;
```

Comment: а как же 2й столбец? Наверное, он должен быть сформирован исходя из распределения по самим векторам. Думаю, что есть более правильное решение этой проблемы.

Comment: @Ste_kd, 2й столбец нельзя восстановить, так как там все NaN

Comment: Можно,если использовать алгоритмы для интерполяции. Ваше решение, не совсем подходит, оно подходит только для конкретного примера и то не для всех столбцов матрицы.